# php echo listbox value from databasebase

Tags: php, listbox

I have 2 tables

```
TABLE joke (id, joke_text, joke_date, author_id)
TABLE author(id, name, email)
```

I am having a problem in echoing the value inserted within author_id field in the list box:

```
        <?php 
    # display all php errors
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    # include dbConnection details
    require '../includes/dbconn.php';

        # initially set $id to empty
        $id = null;

        # if $id is not empty, GET the id
        if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        }

        # if $id is empty then send the user back to index.php
        if ( null==$id ) {
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
        }

        if ( !empty($_POST)) {
            // keep track validation errors
            $joke_textError = null;
            $authorError = null;

            // keep track post values
            $joke_text = $_POST['joke_text'];
            $author_id = $_POST['author_id'];

            // validate input
            $valid = true;
            if (empty($joke_text)) {
                $joke_textError = 'Please enter joke text';
                $valid = false;
            }


            // update data
            if ($valid) {
                $sql = "UPDATE joke set joke_text = ?, author_id = ? WHERE id = ?";
                $update = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
                $update->execute(array($joke_text,$author_id,$id));
                header("Location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT joke.id, joke.joke_text, joke.joke_date, author.name, author.email, joke.author_id, author.id
                    FROM joke INNER JOIN author
                    ON author_id = author.id 
                    WHERE joke.id = ?";
            $select = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
            $select->execute(array($id));
            $data = $select->fetch();
            $joke_id = $data['id'];
            $joke_text = $data['joke_text'];
            $joke_date = $data['joke_date'];
            $author_name = $data['name'];
            $author_email = $data['email'];
            $author_id = $data['author_id'];
                }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Update Author</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/styles.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                            <h1>Update Author</h1>
                        </div>

                        <form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post">
                          <div class="control-group <?php if (!empty($nameError)){ echo 'error';}?>">
                            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input name="joke_text" type="text" placeholder="joke text" value="<?php if (!empty($joke_text)){ echo htmlspecialchars(trim($joke_text)); } ?>">        
                                <?php if (!empty($joke_textError)) { 
                                    echo '<span class="help-inline">' . $joke_textError . '</span>';
                                 } ?>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <select name="author_id" id="author_id">
                        <option value="">Select one</option>
                        <?php 
                        $sql2 = 'SELECT id, name FROM author';
                        foreach ($dbConnection->query($sql2) as $data2) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $data2['id']; ?>" 
                            <?php if(isset($_POST['author_id']) && $_POST['author_id'] == $data['author_id']) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>
                            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data2['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php } ?>



                    </select>

                          <div class="form-actions">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green">Update</button>
                              <a class="btn" href="index.php">Back</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The data updates into the database just fine, can not figure how to echo it back out into the author_id listbox. If someone could kindly give some assistance it would be great!

Comment: Where do you try to echo it back out and what isn't working?

Comment: There is a listbox with authors (author_id) in it, that is where I would want the data to be echo'ed back into.

Comment: It looks like you've already written code to do this.  So what's the problem?

Comment: for example, if author 10 is attached to the record. It will not on page load select author 10 from the listbox automatically. it just shows the blank option first.

Comment: And in what way does it fail?  What is the resulting HTML?  What do you expect it to be?  What are the actual runtime values of the PHP variables being compared?  You need to do at least *some* debugging here.

Comment: done it! needed to modify the isset line.